# Measure of dense $G_{\delta}$-set of a compact metric space

Tags: measure-theory

I try to prove the following:
Suppose that $X$ is a Polish space considered as a dense $G_{\delta}$-set of a compact metric space $\tilde{X}$, and that $\tilde{\mu}$ is a probability measure on $\tilde{X}$.
Then it holds: $\tilde{\mu}(\tilde{X}\setminus X) = 0$.

Unfortunately, I've not the least idea how to do this. You guys can't help me, can you? Even a hint where to start would be wonderful, at all.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are we saying that $X$ inherits its metric from $\bar X$?  If so, doesn't being a dense subset of $\bar X$ and Polish imply that $X = \bar X$?

Comment: Maybe you should consider a $\{\tilde{X} \backslash X\}$ and try to consider it's measure as infimum measure of some nested sequence of sets. Then due to continuity of measure (and density of $X$) you will obtain your statement?

Comment: Yes, X inherits its metric from $\tilde{X}$. But, I don't see why $X=\tilde{X}$? Might you drop a word about that?

Comment: @openspace: I've tried that, but with less success.

Comment: @user6247850: I think what you mean now! $X=cl(L)=\tilde{X}$ where $L$ is a dense $G_{\delta}$-subset of $\tilde{X}$. Could it be that easy?

Comment: @user6247850 I'm not certain, but do you assume that $X$ should be close?

Comment: No, $X$ needn't be closed.

Comment: Since $X$ is Polish, it is homeomorphic to a closed subspace of a Polish space $L$. Letting $L$ be dense and $G_{\delta}$ in $\tilde{X}$, as assumed, would give the result. Isn't it?

Comment: The unit interval has dense open subsets of arbitrarily small Lebesgue measure, for example the complements of fat Cantor sets.